# How to cross validate WDBC.csv breast cancer classification dataset in Stacked Autoencoders?

Tags: cross-validation, autoencoder, binary

I need kind guidance regarding the context of how to cross validate WDBC.csv (Wisconsin Breast cancer diagnostic) dataset for breast cancer binary classification in Stacked Autoencoders as I put the features as X matrix to autoencoder for training and feature learning and then learnt features are used for classification purpose. Don't know how to cross validate it?

Help is much appreciated in anticipation.